# HLS Video Stream Auto Play Iphone

Tags: iphone, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, autoplay

so this is my issue. I was able to autoplay some videos which are not live stream. They are auto playing perfectly using https://github.com/Stanko/html-canvas-video-player but when I place the live stream HLS format, the video does not play, whether auto or via double tap. I would like to know how to auto play a video stream on iphone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS specifically refuses to auto play live streams. This allows the user to controll their data usage considering most people have data caps. Apple is changing this in ios10 however.